# propeller air mass flow equation

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model a hovercraft and I need to obtain an air inlet flow ratio in (kg / s) of a propeller based on its dimensions (it can be the radius) and speed, is there an equation like that? Where could I find it?

Comment: And see the info in the comments made to you here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/565416/152903 you now have sufficient information to continue.

Comment: You have the mass of the device - more than that in kg/s how much more is based on efficiency plus gravity.